# Tezbox sent my wallet balance (240 tezos) to wrong address when transferring balance to my Atomic wallet. Can I get them back?

Tags: transactions, baker, tezbox, transfer, address

I sent the balance of my Tezos to my Atomic tezos Wallet address but they got sent to a different address. I think they may have been sent to the other address to be baked? Sorry if this sounds very newbie but I am. I did as much investigation using the tezos explorer and followed the tokens through a few addresses and have screenshots if that is helpful at all. I also have my tezbox sending address which is tz1WJxrWB8iByX9w7unYbZMKqiMgvdbguBFE and the receiving address was tz1QC8CPFK3aRqkYRWdKPVzWwVX8NPD5dNtH
instead, it went to this address tz1hn2TrTKKLCMYv84FUo2ZkNfC4MAtW6Rqb. Now, this address has a few transactions that he immediately sends to other addresses but he holds mine and one other which he eventually combines into one transaction and sends it on to another address. I have the trail if needed. If someone can please tell me what is going on it would be much appreciated. I thought maybe there was a three-month "process" to "bake" my tokens and was waiting to see if anything happened and it might eventually get sent on to my Atomic wallet. I'm not sure what has happened to them now and if anyone can help me with this, again, it would be very much appreciated. I've looked for similar problems here and elsewhere but none are quite the same. Thanks for listening...

Comment: This question does not belong on the Tezos Stack Exchange. If you have a very specific technical question ask it here, for questions like this one the best place is Tezos Riot, Reddit, or Telegram.

Answer (score 2):

There is a high chance you got scammed by a fake TezBox site. Go back and carefully check the URL. TezBox has been "dead" and unsupported for almost a year and half. There have been several fakes that have surfaced and your story sounds exactly like the others.

Unfortunately, if this is indeed the case, there is absolutely no way to get your Tez back. If you keep following those addresses, you can see that person transfered collected funds to Binance where he likely sold them and cashed out.

Staking your Tez do not involve transferring to anyone or any baker. When you stake, you always retain 100% absolute control of your tokens. They are never locked, never frozen, never required transferring.

Comment: Thanks...This was probably the case then although the tezbox wallet was that old and there was a warning saying it was not supported anymore and was the reason for my wanting to transfer them in the first place. Thank you for taking the time to answer me. I really appreciate it! Unfortunately, I can't vote your answer up because I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: @CryptoDan Please mark as answered when you get a chance